# Emacs prefix key error: why is M-z considered a sequence?

Tags: emacs

I want to set <kbd>viper-toggle-key</kbd> to <kbd>M-z</kbd> (<kbd>C-z</kbd> is undo and only undo!). Looks easy: I just need to add `(setq viper-toggle-key [(meta ?z)])` in `.viper`. Except I get this message:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `d:/Alexey/Home/.emacs.d/init.el':
>
> error: Key sequence M-z starts with non-prefix key

I don't understand why: <kbd>M-z</kbd> is a single key, not a sequence!

Answer (score 3):

`M` is the `meta` key, which is usually not a modifier (like control) - typically it's something like <kbd>ESC</kbd>, which you type *prior* to the other character, e.g. <kbd>ESC</kbd> *then* <kbd>z</kbd>. So meta key combinations are, in general, sequences, rather than single keypresses.

Comment: But why doesn't that imply that _every_ <kbd>M-...</kbd> combination is a sequence? And one which starts with a non-prefix key?